# Use custom keyboard for two different views

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have created a sub-class of `UIViewController`, and the `xib` has a custom keyboard I built. The reason I am using a custom keyboard is that I need a key for a decimal, it needs to be shorter than the native keyboard, and it needs to have only numbers.

The modal view doesn't work because I want it to only come up about halfway, like the native keyboard.

I was able to do it as another view in the same `xib`, but I'm not sure how to call it from a separate `xib` 2 different views will use my keyboard- so I wanted to only create it once rather than add it as another view to both xibs.

Here's how the code looks when I just add another view to the same `xib`. (It works).

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (!calcVisible) {
        [calculatorView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 416, 320, 200)];
        [self.view addSubview:calculatorView];

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3f];
        [calculatorView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 216, 320, 200)];
        [UIView commitAnimations];

        calcVisible = YES;
    }
```

But how would I initialize `calculatorView` from a separate `xib`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The modal view doesn't work because I want it to only come up about
>   halfway, like the native keyboard.

Set your text field's `inputView` property to the view you want to use as the keyboard. In this case, I guess that's `calculatorView`, so somewhere in your view controller's `-viewDidLoad` you'll want to add:

```
textField.intputView = calculatorView;
```

The text field will then display that view instead of the standard keyboard whenever it becomes first responder. You don't have to worry about presenting the view yourself.

> But how would I initialize calculatorView from a separate xib?

That's easy too. Add an outlet to your view controller if you haven't already:

```
@property(strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView* calculatorView;
```

(You'll naturally want to create accessors, probably with `@synthesize`.) Create a .xib named "Calculator.xib" that contains the view you want to use. Select the File's Owner proxy icon in the .xib and set its class to that of your view controller. Then connect the view in the .xib to the `calculatorView` outlet in File's Owner. In your view controller's code, load the .xib file:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Calculator" owner:self options:0];
```

After that, your `calculatorView` property should point to an instance of your view.

Comment: Thanks for your help Caleb, I'm just a little confused. Am I connecting the calculator view and xib to the viewController that is using it, or calculatorView.h? Because I need to use it from two different views- so if I connect it from one, I can't use it from the other right?